# Counting values that meet a condition

Tags: matlab, performance, optimization, count, conditional-statements

I am trying to count the number of times a value in a column vector is greater than `0.5`. The code below gets me where I need to be but I am wondering is this the most efficient way to do this.

```
n = 500
AA = rand(n,1);
for i = 1:n
    if abs(AA(i))>0.5
      BB(i)=1;
    else
      BB(i)=0;
    end
end
sBB = sum(BB);
SD = sBB/n;
```

Comment: You can just do `BB = AA>0.5`.

Comment: thanks! I will accept this as an answer or delete this question. Whatever you advise!

Comment: How does coming from Excel justify your approach? In Excel we would do `=COUNTIF(A1:A4, ">0.5")` - no loops involved. Not trying to sound aggressive, I just want to understand why you decided to use a loop.

Comment: I know your point, I am just trying to figure things out in MATLAB and not thinking straight.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This task can benefit from vectorization:

```matlab
n = 500
AA = rand(n,1); % You used vectorization already (!) and not create each entry separately...
BB = AA>0.5;    % Results in a vector of logicals which signifies where the condition was met
SD = sum(BB)/n; % Can also be `nnz(BB)/n` or `mean(BB)`
```